# atascado con "Connecting to SSH server" mensaje en SSH conectarse a la VM GCP

Tags: wordpress, dns, gcp

Quería iniciar un sitio wordpress vinculado a una máquina GCP que tengo con un dominio que compré en Google Domains. Sin embargo, cuando intento conectarme a la página de administración de mi sitio wordpress desde la página de Instancias VM.

[image: introduzca aquí la descripción de la imagen]

con <kbd>LOG INTO THE ADMIN PANEL</kbd> , me sale :

```
Accès Interdit
Vous n'êtes pas autorisé à accéder à https://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/
```

*Acceso prohibido, No está autorizado a acceder*

Y cuando intento hacerlo desde la url :

```
Accès Interdit
Vous n'êtes pas autorisé à accéder à https://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/?redirect_to=https://thedataclan.com/wp-admin/&reauth=1
```

Creo que es porque el SSL ya no está establecido, pero cuando intento conectarme a la máquina virtual con <kbd>SSH</kbd> no consigo pasar de este mensaje:

```
Connexion au serveur SSH...
```

Entonces, ¿cómo me conecto al servidor SSH de una máquina virtual en GCP para poder añadir el certificado SSL?

## Update

Intenté hoy connectarme con <kbd>SSH</kbd>, y ahora obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado acceder con [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install?hl=es-419)?

Comment: Si, pero el boton non funciona @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Qué botón es el que no funciona?